# Update A Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm working on creating some reporting for the new year. I lifted this code and attempted to make it work for a temp table as I don't have create table rights on my DB. I commented out the PKey portion as I didn't think I needed it in a temp table.

I'm able to insert the Dates through 2099, "N" in BankHoliday and "Null" in `HolidayName` columns in the temp table. But, when I go to run the update portion for "New Years Day" holiday separately or as one long query I get the same syntax error. "Incorrect syntax near ' '." Just when I think I know what I'm doing too...

```
Declare @FirstDate as Date
Declare @LastDate as Date
Declare @WorkingDate as Date

set @FirstDate = '01-01-2010'
SET @LastDate = '12-31-2099'

-- create holiday table replace # with dbo for permanent table
begin
create table #CACFederalReserverHolidays
(
[Date] Date Not Null,
BankHoliday nvarchar(1) Null,
HolidayName nvarchar(50) Null,
) ON [Primary]
end

----add primary key replace # with dbo for permanent table

--begin
--alter table #CACFederalReserverHolidays add constraint
--PK_CACFederalReserverHolidays Primary Key Clustered
--(
--Date
--)
--With (Statistics_NoRecompute = off,
--  Ignore_Dup_Key = Off,
--  Allow_Row_Locks = On,
--  Allow_Page_Locks = On) On [Primary]
--end

-- insert the first date

Insert into #CACFederalReserverHolidays 
([Date],[BankHoliday])
Values
(@FirstDate,'N')

-- insert the remaining dates by adding 1 to the last date
While (select MAX(DATE)
from #CACFederalReserverHolidays
) < @LastDate

begin
Set @WorkingDate =  DATEADD (day,1,(select MAX(DATE) from #CACFederalReserverHolidays))
if @WorkingDate <= @LastDate
    begin
        insert into #CACFederalReserverHolidays
        ([Date], [BankHoliday])
        Values
        (@WorkingDate, 'N')
            end
    else
        break
end

--ID Fed Holidays
begin
update #CACFederalReserverHolidays
 set BankHoliday = 'Y', 
    HolidayName = 'New Year''s Day'
    where DATEPART(day,Date) = 1
    and DATEPART(month,Date) = 1
    and DATEPART(Dw,Date) between 2 and 6
    
update #CACFederalReserverHolidays
     set BankHoliday = 'Y', 
    HolidayName = 'New Year''s Day'
    where DATEPART(day,Date) = 1
    and DATEPART(month,Date) = 1
    and DATEPART(Dw,Date) = 2
end

begin 
-- MLK Day, 3rd Mon in January
update #CACFederalReserverHolidays
 set BankHoliday = 'Y', 
    HolidayName = 'Martin Luther King Day'
    where DATEPART(day,Date) between 15 and 21
    and DATEPART(month,Date) = 1
    and DATEPART(Dw,Date) = 2
end
```

Comment: Try 'New Year'''s Day' or 'New Year''''s Day' - That's three or four single quotes

Comment: even if I try a different holiday I get the same error

Comment: I'm running it on my machine now, I'll see what happens and get back to you shortly

Comment: Okay, I've run the script you've posted ( I also uncommented the primary key constraint, which sped things up a tad) and it ran fine. Have you got a full stop in your script after the '? The error shows one "Incorrect syntax near ' '."  Try copying your code from this page and pasting it into a new window in SSMS

Comment: it didn't like me trying to space apart the code and tab over.  I've deleted the spaces and tabs and it runs.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may have found an actual bug in SQL Server (or in Management Studio).

These two UPDATE statements:

```
update #CACFederalReserverHolidays
 set BankHoliday = 'Y', 
    HolidayName = 'New Year''s Day'
    where DATEPART(day,Date) = 1
    and DATEPART(month,Date) = 1
    and DATEPART(Dw,Date) between 2 and 6
    
update #CACFederalReserverHolidays
     set BankHoliday = 'Y', 
    HolidayName = 'New Year''s Day'
    where DATEPART(day,Date) = 1
    and DATEPART(month,Date) = 1
    and DATEPART(Dw,Date) = 2
```

Appear to have some kind of invalid space characters and/or line breaks within the first two lines.  However, when I scan it one character at a time, I can not find any Unicode values that should cause this.  Nonetheless, when I edit out all of the spaces and line-breaks and then re-enter them by hand, the queries no longer get "Invalid Syntax" errors.

I suggest that you do the same thing.  But first, I would request that you copy these lines and take them to Microsoft Connect and enter them as a possible bug.

(Actually, I'll be happy to enter this into MS Connect, if you want.)

---

I have entered this into Microsoft Connect as a SQL Server bug here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/775641/ssms-throws-spurious-incorrect-syntax-error.  Feel free to go there and upvote or comment on it and/or indicate if you can reproduce it yourself.

---

I just figured it out.  Here is my revised posting for Connect, which explains it pretty well:

> When I execute the following text verbatim in SSMS:
>
> ```
> update #CACFederalReserverHolidays
>  set BankHoliday = 0
> ```
>
> It throws the error "Incorrect syntax near ' '."  As far as I can tell
>   it should just say that the #temp table is undefined.  Note: Even if the
>   #temp table is defined, it throws the same error.
>
> I got this from a user's question on a support forum (here:
>   [Update A Temp Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129706/update-a-temp-table/14130003#14130003)).
>   Cutting and pasting the user's text into my SSMS, I was able to narrow
>   it down to these two lines.  After a lot of editing and testing, I
>   found that the problem would only go away if I removed the line-break
>   and spaces between the first and second line and then re-entered them
>   myself.  Suspecting some invisible/invalid character, I then quoted
>   the text and examined it character by character with:
>
> ```
> select unicode(substring('update #CACFederalReserverHolidays
>  set BankHolidayX = 0', 35,1))
> ```
>
> But looking at characters 35, 36, and 37, only revealed the Unicode
>   values 13, 10, and 63 (CR, LF and Space).
>
> As far as I can tell, this must be a bug, either in Management Studio,
>   or in the SQL Server Parser itself.
>
> Note that I have only reproduced this on SQL Server 2012 so far, but
>   the original user reported it from SQL Server 2008.
>
> ---
>
> OK, I have just realized that my examination procedure above was
>   flawed because I was converting it to ASCII before looking at the
>   Unicode values.  When I use the correct expression:
>
> ```
> select unicode(substring(N'update #CACFederalReserverHolidays
>  set BankHolidayX = 0', 37,1))
> ```
>
> It reveals that character 37 is actually Unicode value 8200.  I am
>   unfamiliar with this but I assume that it is invalid.

---

So long story short, it appears that some of the spaces in the SQL code (specifically the spaces in front of the `set ..` lines after the `update..` are not true spaces (Unicode 63), but are actually Unicode character 8200 ("PUNCTUATION SPACE", U+2008).  Obviously you'll need to replace these with spaces.

Comment: wow thanks a lot for all that leg work. I had done a lot of editing of it myself and actually retyped everything that I had lifted from someone else because I was throwing errors that I figured were do to spacing.  I'm away from the office and will try in the am

Comment: Amazing, yes, that is EXACTLY it.  Spacing issues.  In an attempt to make the code look neat and organized I got errors.  Thanks for all your assistance.

Comment: more specifically I think Tab Key issues

Answer (score 0):

What is the `begin` for after `--ID Fed Holidays`?

Those don't make sense there.  They only make sense for beginning and ending the `while` loop.

IDK if that is the cause of your problem, but that's the first thing I noticed

Comment: those are comments for me.  It's meant to remind me its the portion of the code where I identify the federal holidays

Comment: I'm not referring to the comment, I'm refering to the `begin` after the comment.  `begin`/`end` only makes sense where you have them for the `while` loop.  Everywhere else you have a begin/end I'm pretty sure they shouldn't be there.